# Pandas merges 2 columns into one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I successfully can connect and read SharePoint lists via the Office 365 Sharepoint REST API in Python.

From the for loop I want to bring it into a data frame. Currently I have no idea, why I get a data frame where all columns are getting combined into one.

[Code with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzbLM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary in for loop and then convert it to `pd.DataFrame(dict)`.

```
my_dict = {"Spalte":[],"Spalte1":[]}

for item in items:
   my_dict["Spalte"].append(item.properties['Spalte'])
   my_dict["Spalte1"].append(item.properties['Spalte1'])

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

The above method can produce the output you want.